# Subnets creation Based on Availability Zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

AWS Using Cloud Formation Template(CFT)Depending on Azs Subnets should be created and should get CIDR range also automatically.

Single CFT should work this.

For Ex: if a region has 3 Azs it should create 3 subnets or if it has 2 Azs it should create 2 subnets

Comment: What have you tried ?